# How to get all data from qt model

Tags: python, c++, qt, model

I have created a QIdentityProxyModel called proxymodel that extends a QSqlTableModel called sourcemodel by adding 3 calculated columns. 
The calculated columns are made by traversing the sourcemodel and storing the data in a list that is mapped by the proxymodel.
The proxymodel is displayed in a TableView.

The problem i have is that unless i interact with the TableView the models only load the first 256 registers of 5426 total, so initially i can only perform calculations on these first 256 rows.

I wish to fill the list with the calculations on the 5426 row.
please! help me get this done? Any ideas woukd be helpful

The project is written in pyqt so be free to answer however you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL models use the progressive fetch. The source model returns `true` from `canFetchMore`. The view calls `fetchMore`, and then more rows are added to the source model by fetching them from the database - only when the view needs them.

Since your proxy needs all the data, it should invoke `fetchMore` on the source model during idle time (using a zero-duration timer). It should also properly track the source getting more rows inserted to it!

```
class MyProxy : public QIdentityProxyModel {
  Q_OBJECT
  QMetaObject::Connection m_onRowsInserted;
  ...
  /// Update the computed results based on data in rows first through last
  /// in the source model.
  void calculate(int first, int last);
  void onRowsInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int first, int last) {
    calculate(int first, int last);
  }
  void onSourceModelChanged() {
    disconnect(m_onRowsInserted);
    m_onRowsInserted = connect(sourceModel(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted,
                               this, &MyProxy::onRowsInserted);
    fetch();
  }
  void fetch() {
    if (!sourceModel()->canFetchMore(QModelIndex{})) return;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this]{
      if (!sourceModel()->canFetchMore(QModelIndex{})) return;
      sourceModel()->fetchMore(QModelIndex{});
      fetch();
    });
  }
public:
  MyProxy(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QIdentityProxyModel{parent} {
    connect(this, &QAbstractProxyModel::sourceModelChanged,
            this, &MyProxy::onSourceModelChanged);
  }
};
```